# when I called a function under stack widget page it multiples the line edit operation of specific widget

Tags: pyqt, qstackedwidget

SO , I am new in the Pyqt design. I use stacked widget for the setup and I do some operations in each widget. My problem is that, for example when I enter a number, say 50, in lineedit slot of Page2 it is fine I print what I enter. that is 50. Problem is when I leave the page and return, and If I enter 50 again, it prints 50, and 50. in my third revisiting page I print three 50s... and so on. below is my code. I couldnt understand why and I need to fix that. I appreciate if you can help me

class loadUi_example(QMainWindow):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.ui= Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    self.TAHA_2_Training_Page_NumofFilter_object=TAHA_2_Training_Page_NumofFilter()

    self.home_page_index =0
    self.book_list_page_index =1
    self.add_book_page_index =2
    self.user_list_page_index =3
    self.add_user_page_index =4



    self.ui.actionHome_Page.triggered.connect(self.go_home_page)
    self.ui.actionBooks.triggered.connect(self.go_training_page)
    self.ui.actionAdd_Book.triggered.connect(self.go_addbook_page)
    self.ui.actionUsers.triggered.connect(self.go_users_page)
    self.ui.actionAdd_User.triggered.connect(self.go_add_user_page)

def go_addbook_page (self):
    self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page_7)
    pass

def go_training_page (self):
    self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page_2)
    self.ui.lineEdit_14.returnPressed.connect(self.training_page_line_edit_process)
    self.ui.lineEdit_14.setPlaceholderText("Number of Epoch, hit Enter")

def training_page_line_edit_process(self):
    epochs = self.ui.lineEdit_14.text()
    print ("epochs: ", epochs)
```

Comment: Connections are not unique by default. If you connect a signal twice to the same function, that function will be called twice when the signal is emitted: every time `go_training_page` is called, a new connection is created. Move the `returnPressed` connection to the `__init__`.

Comment: thank you @musicamante it works. Eventually, I modified the setup and construct classes for each widget page. And I defined definitions under related class. This makes everthing more neat.

Comment: Ok, If it answers your question, you should accept the duplicate message.

Comment: I accepted it. Bu I didnt get what u mean "duplicate message"